# Why is this std::out_of_range being thrown in this function?

Tags: c++

Below is the function where this error occurs:

```
std::string DataTranslation::getMeshName(std::string meshLink)
{
    File input(this->datafilename);
    std::cout << "the line count of " << this->datafilename << " = " << input.lineCount() << ".\n";
    std::cout << "code above is working properly if this prints.\n";
    return "_";
}
```

Runtime:

```
the line count of ./res/data/resourcelist.data = 6.
code above is working properly if this prints.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what(): vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

That's literally it. Previously, the function was a lot more complex, and during the debugging process I commented it all out, leaving me with what I have written above. The exception appears to be thrown due to `return "_";`.

Am I making an elementary error or is this odd indeed?

Comment: Perhaps what is calling it is going pear shaped

Comment: Which File library are you using? The problem is probably from it, in its destructor, after calling linecount before. Try opening the File first (files typically need to be `.open`'d) and closing it at the end, it may fix the problem. Or ask whoever coded it if it's an internal library.

Comment: You need to post an [mcve].

Comment: It is my own File library. The constructor copies the parameter to a private variable and does nothing else. In addition, I commented out the File line and the line count line entirely. The error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
```

`terminate` being called is typically due to an exception "escaping" a destructor.

```
what(): vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

This is typically thrown when you do a checked access (think `.at()`) to an element in an `std::vector`.

So, look for a wrong checked vector access inside `File` destructor. Even better, to debug this kind of problem run your program inside a debugger, maybe even add a breakpoint over exceptions being thrown (or over `std::terminate`); notice that with `gdb` this shouldn't even be necessary - `std::terminate` results in a `SIGABRT`, which automatically breaks into the debugger.

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/matteo/scratch/a.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff76c1418 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: File o directory non esistente.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff76c1418 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff76c301a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7ae484d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7ae26b6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7ae2701 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7ae2919 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x000000000040077e in A::~A() ()
#7  0x0000000000400729 in foo() ()
#8  0x0000000000400749 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: The 'File' class has an empty destructor. In addition, I commented out the File line, and the error remains. The error does not appear to be caused by File.
Edit: The File class has a superclass of which had a constructor which accessed a malformed vector. Thank you, well spotted.